# CollectionView Cell Rounded Corners not Working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a prototype cell for a collection view and am trying to make the edges rounded, but I can't figure out how to use self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0 and make it work. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import UIKit

final class TagCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let textLabel: UILabel

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        self.textLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        self.textLabel.setFont(14)
        self.textLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.textLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.textLabel.backgroundColor = .red
        self.textLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0

        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true

        self.contentView.addSubview(textLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.textLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            self.textLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            self.textLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            self.textLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Comment: "but I can't figure out how to use self.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0" Your code never says _anything_ about `self.layer`.

Answer (score 2):

it's better to create a subView inside the contentView and apply the corner to it

```
self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0

self.contentView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't seem to be working when I add constants to the  auto layout so that the text isn't right on the border of the cell, but has some space between?

Comment: show me that line of code  to better understand the case

Comment: Ok, I edited the code to show the constants I added to the auto layout to try to make the label more insulated, and not on the border